# Gulp serve > Parsing error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: angularjs, gulp, form-data

I am getting this parsing error whenever I try to gulp serve. 
This is the code for which gulp is giving error. I have written a function which takes up a object of `FormData` type and checks for any of its value to be undefined and if it is then set it to blank string.

```
 function setUndefinedFields(data) {
            for (var pair of data.entries()) {
                if (pair[1] === 'undefined') {
                    data.set(pair[0], '');
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

But when I perform gulp serve it gives parsing error: unexpected identifier in terminal and in browser console it shows this error

[image]

Although if I comment the function perform gulp serve and uncomment the function, then the code works fine.

Edit :
This function is called after appending form data values

```
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('jobTitle', vacancy.jobTitle);
    data.append('compulsoryReqs', vacancy.compulsoryReqs);
    data.append('preferredReqs', vacancy.preferredReqs);
    data.append('company', vacancy.company);

    data = setUndefinedFields(data);
```

Now if any of the field value is undefined the function will replace the value with ''.

Comment: Need more context. We have no idea how that function fits into your app

Comment: the error you pasted from the console is usually related to angular injection so I don't think it's related. it usually means you either forgot to add a dependency file to `index.html`, or forgot to add it in `angular.module('<app_name>', ['<name_of_dep>']]);`

Comment: @Thatkookooguy a syntax error in a component will cause it also